# Generate a signature using a key sha256rsa

Tags: flutter, dart

I form a signature using a Kotlin key.
Now I need to port this to Flutter and got a lot of problems.

```
@Throws(SecurityException::class)
private fun sha256rsa(key: String, data: String): String {
    val trimmedKey = key.replace("-----\\w+ PRIVATE KEY-----".toRegex(), "")
        .replace("\\s".toRegex(), "")
    return try {
        val result = Base64.decode(trimmedKey, Base64.DEFAULT)
        val factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
        val keySpec: EncodedKeySpec = PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(result)
        val signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA")
        signature.initSign(factory.generatePrivate(keySpec))
        signature.update(data.toByteArray())
        val encrypted = signature.sign()
        Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.NO_WRAP)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        throw SecurityException("Error calculating cipher data. SIC!")
    }
}
```

Maybe someone did this or knows in which direction to look?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to communicate with the native platform code. Please see below link;

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: I thought about that too. But isn't it then still necessary to do the implementation on IOS?

Comment: if you need it on both platforms then yes you need to implement both native. If you don't need you can use isPlatform function to ignore iOS.

and also please check out if what you are trying to achieve isn't already done as a pub package.